# ios Image text and colour enhancement filter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image-processing, uiimage

I am trying CIFilter and GPUImage filter to apply various effects (brightness, contrast, saturation, etc.) on an image, but I'm struggling, would need an enhancement like the one shown below:

**Before Enhancement filter**

[image: Before Enhancement filter:]

**After Enhancement filter**

[image: After Enhancement filter]

CIFilter code that I tried:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ CIDetectorImageOrientation :
                               [[resultImage properties] valueForKey:kCGImagePropertyOrientation] };
NSArray *adjustments = [resultImage autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
for (CIFilter *filter in adjustments) {
    [filter setValue:resultImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    resultImage = filter.outputImage;
}
```

GPUImage Filter:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Msource.png"];
GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter alloc] init];
stillImageFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 10.0;// adjust this to tweak the blur radius of the filter, defaults to 4.0

UIImage *filteredImage = [stillImageFilter imageByFilteringImage:inputImage];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response I will update my question

Comment: What filter do you want to use? Do you know what filter your example image is using - looks like a fade?

Answer (score 3):

//Hope this helps , its in swift 3 :

```
        var aCIImage = CIImage();
        var contrastFilter: CIFilter!;
        var brightnessFilter: CIFilter!;
        var gaussianBlurFilter: CIFilter!;
        var pointFilter: CIFilter!;
        var vignettFilter : CIFilter!;
        var context = CIContext();
        var outputImage = CIImage();
        var newUIImage = UIImage();
        var finalImage = UIImage()
    
       DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.gaussianBlurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIExposureAdjust");
                            self.gaussianBlurFilter.setValue(self.aCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")
                            
                            self.gaussianBlurFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: sender.value), forKey: "inputEV");
                            
                            self.outputImage = self.gaussianBlurFilter.outputImage!;
                            
                            let imageRef = self.context.createCGImage(self.outputImage, from: self.outputImage.extent)
                            
                            self.newUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)
                            self.testView?.image = self.newUIImage;
                    }


 //
```

[image: Dark Image with text and having no filters applied to it]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1STp.png

[image: Same Image with text and having CIExposureAdjust Filter applied to it]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU0Oz.png

Link: For the demo project.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-EIC_4IXtA9UjFwT3o0dXI1OTA

Comment: I guess this can be achieved by "CIExposureAdjust" filter also. hope i was able to help you out .

Comment: Don't know why its not working for you but its a tested code .I have performed the same operation that your doing. I have attached an image as well please have a look to it. Initially it was a dull image, this image is after applying the filter.

Comment: @SwiftyCodes you can update with a test using Asker's own image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYpC5.jpg

Comment: @VC.One see the uploaded image now! Though the image that is in the sticker view is not full but still you can see the affect that has been applied, I guess its working! and i used a slider to decrease and increase the exposureAdjust intensity as well by the way I did this using GPUImage Filter also but in swift only. I hope I was able to help you :)

Comment: Thanks for updating. Now the Asker can see how this Answer applies to their problem / image.

Comment: @swifty thanks for updating but your code still never enhance text in image and also it will enhance white background type image not other.

Comment: @ManikandanD : Bro, its not like that I have been using this code to enhance the images and the images with text on them too. And also the images that have a dark background , I am uploading a image that was initially dark and also having a text on it and I will upload the same image after applying the CIExposureAdjust Filter too. Please have a look to the uploaded images now. Is this not the result that your trying to achieve?

Comment: @SwiftyCodes, Okay I will check and give you the accepted answer, Can you able share sample example project.

Comment: @ManikandanD : I'll create the same for you. Give me some time.

Comment: @ManikandanD : I have shared a link for the project find the same. Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: @ManikandanD : was it helpful ??